# How many total events it will display in Month/week/daily view on the FullCalendar trial version (V3) package

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

We are using FullCalendar free version (V3). How many total events it will display In Month/week/daily view is there any limit on the FullCalendar trial version (V3) package.

We have implemented this functionality for few users, we want to enhance the functionality to increase the number of users, by adding users is there any performance issues / limit issue by on the FullCalender V3.

I want to know is there any limit on the total number of events that will display in FullCalendar free version (V3), on monthly /weekly/daily view?

Comment: You will get better performance from the newer versions of fullCalendar - v3 is old and outdated now, and does not receive support or updates. If you are making a new application or feature, there is no reason to use such an old version. Use the latest version 6 and you will get better performance.

Comment: But to address the specific question, there is no hard limit published anywhere about how many events or resources the calendar can hold. It will depend a bit on the efficiency of your backend, the efficiency of the browser's JS engine and the amount of memory & CPU available to it on the device it's running on. Realistically though, you will probably first run into a limit on the number of events it is reasonable to display in the space available without degrading the user experience by making it unreadable or making the quantity of information on display unmanageable for a human brain.

Comment: As for a limit on "users", fullCalendar has no concept of users, so it's a bit unclear what you mean by that - I guessed you actually meant resources (1 resource to represent each user?), or maybe events.

Comment: Thank you ADyson for responding quickly,we have implemented our functionlaity and using this Fullcander trail version(V3) from the past 2 years,
So my question is, is there a limit on the number of events that will load in monthly /weekely/daily view in the Fullcander or there any package/license limit issue ,if we are loading more number of events for different users.

Comment: I've already answered that (see my 2nd comment) - there's no specific limit, you may run into performance issues due to the ability of the browser and hardware where the calendar is being displayed, but it's far more likely you'll run into usability issues before that point, due to the volume of data being unmanageable. If you have that many events on a single calendar, consider having some kind of filtering rules implemented, to stop the user being overloaded with excessive information in one display that they cannot humanly comprehend or process.